# Reading plugin settings in esnext wordpress block

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I am currently trying to create a Wordpress-Plugin that in itself creates a few gutenberg blocks. I want to have some global settings set with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/. But I cant for the life of me find a way to read those values in those gutenberg blocks.

What I would be using those settings for:

```
<div data-attribute="default-setting"></div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a block should always generate the same output based on its attributes, otherwise it'll fail validation in the editor when it's next opened and you'll see an error. If the HTML markup of your blocks depends on things that aren't in the attributes, then you need to do server side rendering. Otherwise you're headed down a dead end, that's not how blocks work. If you shared with us what it is you're trying to do that requires this then perhaps the question would be answerable

Comment: I am currently migrating a piece of software from an other CMS. That software allows to create some Slideshows and a search against an API with AJAX where objects are stored, output those hits as a List View and link those hits to a Detail View. What I wanted to do in settings are things like: List-View URL, Detail View URL, maybe some theming I could, of course just add links to the component, but I thought that that is no fun if you use mutliple instances. So are blocks the wrong way to do this? I liked the Idea of incorporating those into the content.

Comment: I think there's unfinished specification work here, I'm not sure what to suggest without more information. Surely a search AJAX functionality is just javascript loaded on the frontend? If so what does that have to do with displaying blocks in the editor? It's not clear too me what these detail view and list view URLs are or how they factor in. And what is it searching? Is there a slideshow custom post type? You're probably going to need to use server side rendered blocks

Comment: Otherwise, if it was clearer what you were trying to do, other solutions might be possible, e.g. if this block was an embed, and you had a global control over wether to display the title of embeds, then CSS could do the job at a global level on the frontend, with an editor stylesheet reproducing the effect in the editor, but I cannot tell from what you've described how the data is structured and how it's intended to be displayed

Comment: I added an example to my post. I am using multiple data-attributes that configure the URLs to some APIs. I would love to atleast be aple to set default values in the global settings. The blocks work alright so far but I would prefer it to not having to type in cryptic API calls into every block I add. Especially since some of those settings are seldom touched.